# Textarea в ячейке таблицы неправильно расширяется

Tags: javascript, css

Добрый день!
Мне нужна твоя помощь, %username% !
Вот табличка, в ней ты можешь найти textarea: [tablichka](http://jsfiddle.net/6jyLsLev/).

Задача простая, необходимо, чтобы textarea могла расширяться только вправо и вниз. Когда она ползет вниз, второй контрол должен стоять на месте.
Помогите, подскажите!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6jyLsLev/1/ ну если уж совсем быстро и грубо, то можно так :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа такого?
http://jsfiddle.net/6jyLsLev/2/

Comment: Accurately!